# How to find this probability with PDF from TransformedDistribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I need to find the expression for the following equation, where $m>0$

```
Probability[y≤m,y\[Distributed]TransformedDistribution[x^2,x\[Distributed]RiceDistribution[v,Sqrt[α/2]]]]
```

But, MMA does not give me what I want. any help. Am I using the right syntax?

Comment: 1) `I` has a special meaning in Mathematica as the imaginary unit, so you shouldn't use it as your variable; more in general, try to avoid uppercase variable names altogether. 2) when you specify the distribution of `y`, I think you should use the transformed distribution directly, not its PDF.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/113617/27951

Comment: @MarcoB, thanks for your comment. I have tried with your suggestion. It still does not work......

Comment: Have you tried writing the integral yet? Are you familiar without how to do that? Use PDF to get the PDF of the Rice Distribution. 

Integrate[(
  2 E^(-((t^2 + v^2)/\[Alpha]))
    t BesselI[0, (2 t v)/\[Alpha]])/\[Alpha] t^2, {t, 0, m}]

Comment: There's no reason to believe there's a solution to this problem. You may have to use an approximation instead.

Comment: As @Searke mentioned, it is very possible that you just can't get a symbolic answer. You can still assign reasonable values to your $m$, $v$, $\alpha$ parameters, and use `NProbability` to obtain a numerical value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@wolfies essentially gave you the answer in your [original question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/113617/how-to-obtain-the-pdf-of-variable-that-is-square-of-a-rician-distributed-variabl) where he wrote

```
PDF[TransformedDistribution[x^2, x \[Distributed] RiceDistribution[v, Sqrt[α/2]]], y]
```

Just change PDF to CDF (and avoid the use of `I` as @MarcoB recommended):

```
CDF[TransformedDistribution[x^2, x \[Distributed] RiceDistribution[v, Sqrt[α/2]]], y]
```

[image: Cumulative distribution function]

Comment: Huh. I assumed Integrate would have found that when I wrote it out. I wonder if I did something wrong or if Integrate didn't find it.